# How to import Module.exports from another file javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export

I am trying to import a file from its module. exports so I can get functions etc from it. I have this right now from my bot.js file (This is just exported and Constructor part of the file. Full file here: https://pastebin.com/kA39fsPV)

```
const { Client, Collection } = require("discord.js");

class EconomyClient extends Client {
    constructor() {
        super();
}
}
module.exports = EconomyClient;
```

Here is index.js. I am trying to import functions from inside Economy Client.

```
const EconomyClient = require(`./bot.js`);
const client = EconomyClient.EconomyClient
```

I think the way I am importing this is incorrect, but I am not sure how to import the functions and other parts properly. How would I do that properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that when you declare class, if you call the class without "new" its means you cannot call the constructor without new Class()
Because class is not a variable , the javascript think that is a variable or function name you just export.
const client = new myclass(param)

module.exports = client

Or
Just wrap like this on your project

```
module.exports = class EconomyClient extends Client {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are importing is okay but I think it's due to the way you are initiating the client instance in the index.js file. It should be like this -

```
const client = new EconomyClient()
```

Comment: I get the error that TypeError: EconomyClient is not a constructor on
const client = new EconomyClient()

Comment: Seeing your last comment in the other answer...... The EconomyClient is basically the blueprint, and when you create an instance, that's the "client" constant, you are creating a client that follows the EconomyClient blueprint. You can think of the EconomyClient as a blueprint for a car and the client as a car produced from that blueprint.

Comment: Sorry I dont really get that. Can you please show some examples?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to come up with another good example at the moment but I recommend you check out this short video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AWRivBk0Gw&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

Moreover, I think you may have some error in your EconomyClient class or the Client class, if you used the code I added to the first answer and it still doesn't work. Because if you did change and get the constructor error, the index.js file is okay and so is the exporting part that is the module.exports line. So I believe the source of the error may be EconomyClient or Client class.